# DocumentSnapshot Listener

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a question how do i listen to real-time changes to a document snapshot based on the email of the `currentUser` in a `initState`. I knew that `QuerySnapshot` will need to use `documents.forEach` to be able to retrieve but how about `DocumentSnapshot`. This is my code:

```
@override
  void initState() async{
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    Firestore.instance.collection('user').document(user.email).snapshots()
    .listen((userinfo){
      userinfo((userI){
        _fname = userI.data['FullName'];
        _SSID = userI.data['SSID'];
        _email = userI.data['email'];
        _image = userI.data['image'];
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

I am able to get the `user.email` but not able to listen to the Firestore. I can't really find anything that is similar to this maybe it's a relatively easy problem to solve for I'm still new to Flutter and Firebase. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `userI.data()['some_key']` instead of `userI.data['some_key']`.

https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/data.html

Also reomve `userInfo`, it should be like this:

```dart
Firestore.instance.collection('user').document(user.email).snapshots().listen((userI) {
  _fname = userI.data()['FullName'];
  _SSID = userI.data()['SSID'];
  _email = userI.data()['email'];
  _image = userI.data()['image'];
});
```

Comment: oright thanks but im still getting an error from userinfo as the expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked.

Comment: updated my answer. Also take care of null-safety.

Comment: Sir got it to work. But they asked me to remove the `()` in `userI.data()` as the expression doesn't evaluate to a function as well so i remove it. After that when launching it, it shows that `initState()` should not be in a `Future` form then i added another void to do the following but whenever i start to load the page it says that my `NetworkImage` is null but with this `super.initState()` the String for the image URL should have been saved into the string right? Why is it still getting errors that it is null. Sorry for such a lengthy comment and thank you so much for your help.

Comment: what is the version of cloud_firestore are you using? Make sure to check whether `_image` is null or not. Data from firestore would be loaded in async manner so it would be null initially.

Comment: im using `cloud_firestore: ^0.13.7`. yaya initially it will be null because i did not give any value to the String beforehand but the in the InitState() i should have given it a value to the String. But i dont understand how come it is still null.

Comment: Execution is asynchronous. You could use FutureBuilder or do a setState once values are received from Firestore. Use conditions to render something else when values are null.

Comment: yaya i forgot to add `SetState` in. I am able to get the data that i wanted now. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

You can move your asynchronous logic into a different function and call it in your `initState` like this:

```dart
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getUserData();
  }

  Future<void> _getUserData() async {
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    Firestore.instance.collection('user').document(user.email).snapshots()
      .listen((userinfo) {
        setState((){
          _fname = userinfo.data['FullName'];
          _SSID = userinfo.data['SSID'];
          _email = userinfo.data['email'];
          _image = userinfo.data['image'];
        });  
    });
  }
```

And in the widget where you use the variables, you can easily add a null check and display an empty value or a loading indicator.

```dart
Text(_fname??'')
```

or

```dart
_fname == null ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()) : Text(_fname)
```

Comment: thankyou for your reply i am able to get it work now. Thanks a lot. You have also given me the insight of displaying a empty value and a loading indicator. Learn something new thanks man. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Glad to help! :)